# How can I install Django in my Docker file?

Tags: django, docker

I am a newbie to Docker. I have created one Django project and can run it in Docker. However, I have started a second project and have encountered a problem.

I created a virtual env and entered it

```
pipenv install django~=3.1.0 && pipenv shell
```

I created a Django project

```
django-admin startproject config .
```

I ran it within the virtualenv

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and could see the Django spaceship

I then exited the virtualenv and created a Dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

I ran

```
docker build .
```

and it reported a successful build

I created a docker-compose.yml file

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

When I run

```
docker-compose up
```

it complains

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

I have read in the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894761/docker-django-build-fail-couldnt-import-django) that virtual envs should not be used in docker files, so I replaced

```
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
```

with

```
RUN pip install django~=3.1.0
```

but I still get the same error.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing your list of requirements from a separate file, something like this?

```
COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Once you have it installed you can run `docker-compose run web /bin/sh` to start a shell and then use `django-admin startproject` to create a django project. You may need to change the path in the docker-compose file so that it reflects where your manage.py file ended up (I moved mine to the root). I was able to get it working with the following:

**requirements.txt**

`django==3.1.0`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

File tree looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I like the idea of the requirements file as it simplifies and decouples everything